# __getDataType error

Tags: c++, ros

I am getting this strange error for line # 407.

```
 /home/data/rover_workspace/src/mobility/src/mobility.cpp:407:62:   required from here
    /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/message_traits.h:143:36: error: request for member ‘__getDataType’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’
         return m.__getDataType().c_str();
```

I am new to ROS so the exact meaning of this error, and more importantly how to fix it escapes me. Here is line 391 - 408, where the error is occurring in mobility.cpp.

```
case STATE_MACHINE_ROTATE: {
    stateMachineMsg.data = "ROTATING";
    // Calculate the diffrence between current and desired
    // heading in radians.
    float errorYaw = angles::shortest_angular_distance(currentLocation.theta, goalLocation.theta);

    // If angle > 0.4 radians rotate but dont drive forward.
    if (fabs(angles::shortest_angular_distance(currentLocation.theta, goalLocation.theta)) > rotateOnlyAngleTolerance) {
        // rotate but dont drive  0.05 is to prevent turning in reverse
        sendDriveCommand(0.05, errorYaw);
        break;
    } else {
        // move to differential drive step
        stateMachineState = STATE_MACHINE_SKID_STEER;
        //fall through on purpose.
    } //ERROR HERE
}
```

Any explanation as to what going wrong would be great!

The entire mobility.cpp file is found here http://pastebin.com/8ZxuY5QQ

Comment: I think you're going to need to post more code, including types of various things that you are currently showing. It's not obvious what code is calling that, and if that is 391-408, and the error is on 407, well, there is nothing on 407 other than a curly brace. So, something is not quite right with what's posted.

Comment: Good point, I will include the full code now.

Comment: Did you change the code since you got the error? 407:62 is linenumber:columnnumber, and line 407 is still that brace, and there is no code beyond the brace, so column 62 makes no sense. Generally, from the error, it looks like you should be using the `Float64` datatype instead of just `double`, wherever the error is picking up `double` from.

Comment: Looking a little closer, I wonder if it's your calls to `thetaPublish.publish( (currentLocation.theta ) );`. I'm not familiar with ros/etc., but maybe the `theta` is a `float`, and the value needs to be wrapped in a `std_msgs::Float32` since it seems that's what `thetaPublish` is expecting.

Comment: Great points I understand the Error now.

Comment: To me it sounds like message type mishap. I agree that `double` as a type is actually (message-wise) unknown and you have to use the `Float` types (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs) for info on the `std_msgs`).

Answer (score 1):

Okay so your problem is that you are trying to send thetaPublish a std_msgs::Float64 when theta publish can only publish std_msgs::Float32. I would recommend making the publisher publish the float64 instead.

However, you are going to have problems because ROS:INDIGO is out dated and publishers cannot send float64. You should update your ROS version.